# Caliburn.Micro Starting the bootstrapper from code?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

Normally I just but the bootstrapper in the resources of the App.xaml, but for an app I'm building I need code execution to begin elsewhere and then start the bootstrapper up once I'm done my initialization code.

How can I start the bootstrapper?

I set the App.xaml to call a function as then did this:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private AdminBootstrapper b;

        private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            //DO initialization

            b = new AdminBootstrapper();
            b.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run nothing happens, and my view does not appear. I know the view/viewmodel work because if I put the bootstrapper in the resources section of the App.xaml it appears.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe it's too early in the startup phase - this is probably the reason it works in the resources: the bootstrapper gets instantiated when the resources are parsed and loaded - maybe OnStartup is too early for CM to find the bits necessary to register stuff. The very act of creating a new bootstrapper calls `Bootstrapper.Start` so you don't need to call this manually

Comment: Oh did you call `InitializeComponent` in your app constructor by the way? That's usually important!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want it to run a piece of code BEFORE it attempts to load any viewmodels or views. Then when I'm ready call it. Which is why I'm trying to start it in the code.

Comment: Isn't that the point of the bootstrapper virtual methods such as Configure/OnStartUp/StartRuntime/StartDesigntime? Put code in there to configure stuff before CM opens the root view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the "correct" way to use the bootstrapper, the bootstrapper IS the place were you do the setup you talk of. The whole point is to provide a place were Caliburn.Micro knows you are going to set up. Without seeing your bootstrapper though it is impossible to know what is wrong.

The root ViewModel is not loaded until after Configure is called. This is your extensibility point. If you need to do complex configuration you could call a couple of overrides here and then derive a class which exposes these methods.

In general though you would need to provide more information about what you are doing before I could give you a concrete recipe.

Comment: Might be worth pointing to the docs http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper&referringTitle=Documentation which shows customising bootstrapper etc - not sure why people don't read these more often because 99% of answers to common questions are in the docs (they aren't structured like a reference but all the info is there)

Comment: We are working through the docs at the moment to give them a sprucing with a view to make info easier to find. But yep the docs pretty much have all that good stuff in them. :)

Comment: Additionally - you can subclass `BoostrapperBase` if you need to control when CM starts up since this base class doesn't call `Start` upon instantiation.

Comment: need a hand with anything? I'd be happy to contribute

Comment: Your best to ask on the project page itself. Cheers.

Comment: I started with Caliburn.Micro  at bootstrapper Start() doesn't exist. 
I am working with the latest inheriting from BootstrapperBase..
Their examples doesn't run either with the same error.. 
What should I do ?

Comment: @Gregory your best bet is to make a new question, Caliburn.Micro is of a much higher version now so this info might be out of date.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Initialize()` method instead of `Start()`.  I had the same error and searched the internet and found a post that said to use `Initialize()` instead.  I tried it on the sample app in the Caliburn.Micro docs and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the correct way (wanted to remove it from the markup) but still, this code seems to work...

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    MyBootstrapper _bootstrapper;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _bootstrapper = new MyBootstrapper();   
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}

public class MyBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    public MyBootstrapper()
    {
        Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Caliburn.Micro  at bootstrapper Start() doesn't exist. 
I am working with the latest inheriting from BootstrapperBase..
Their examples doesn't run either with the same error.. 
What should I do ? Where the start comes from ?